# Restrict menu rules of custom module

Tags: admin, adminhtml, rules

I created a custom grid list to show more information about orders but I am failing to limit access to it. My **adminhtml.xml** is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <comprandoforareports translate="title">
                    <title>Venda Detalhada</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/order/</action>
                </comprandoforareports>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <sales>
                        <children>
                            <comprandoforareports translate="title">
                                <title>Venda Detalhada</title>
                                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            </comprandoforareports>
                        </children>
                    </sales>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

I tried to put `<acl> ... </acl>` tag on **config.xml** inside of `<adminhtml>..</adminhtml>` too.

The option to enable this menu appears when I try to edit a role, but even disable this appears for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<all>` tag in your adminhtml.xml file and try if that works.

```
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
```